# Soap PHP WSDL XML formatting

Tags: php, xml, soap, formatting, wsdl

So I am using Soap client in PHP and I'm trying to make a request on some WSDL. I try to have a specific output but it seems a bit far from what I try to do. Maybe I don't do this right. I'm a bit new to WSDL.

Here is the result I want:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <loc:sendSms>
           <loc:addresses>9000000000</loc:addresses>
           <loc:senderName>9000000</loc:senderName>
           <loc:message>test SMS</loc:message>
    </loc:sendSms>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

This is what I try to fit my requirement, but it ends with a server error:

```
            $MCIResp = (array) $_soapClient->__soapCall('sendSms', 
                'sendMessage' => array(
                    'addresses' => '9000000000',
                    'senderName' => '9000000',
                    'message'   => 'test SMS '

            )
        );
```

And this is the error I get from this request:

> "SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no
>   'sendmessage' property";

**EDIT: Made some improvements on that by getting inspiration on some posts**

Here is my code now:

```
$_soapClient = new SoapClient(
        null,
        array(
            'location' => 'http://someIP/parlayxsmsgw/services/SendSmsService?wsdl',
            'uri' => 'http://someIP/parlayxsmsgw/services/SendSmsService?wsdl',
            'trace' => 1,
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
            'use' => SOAP_LITERAL,
            'style' => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
             'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array(
                'http' => array(
                    'header' => 'servicekey: someservicekey'
                ),
            )),             
        )
    );
    $params = new \SoapVar("<sendSms><addresses>90000000000</addresses><senderName>90000000</senderName><message>test SMS</message></sendSms>",XSD_ANYXML);
```

And then I do a

```
$_soapClient->whatEverNameHereWillBeIgnored($params);
```

This is now the XML I generate:

```
  <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <sendSms>
       <addresses>989127184955</addresses>
       <senderName>98307066</senderName>
       <message>test SMS</message>
      </sendSms>
     </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But I receive this as a response:

> Unexpected subelement sendSms

do the "loc:" are mandatory to solve this ? Because when I add it in the raw xml it says that

> Undeclared namespace prefix "loc"

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise you to use a WSDL to PHP generator such as [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator), it will ease you the request construction so you won't have to wonder how to construct the request, it will be cristal clear.